# Cassandra : impact of high compaction/streaming throughput values?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

The defaults throughput are as follow (cassandra.yaml) :

```
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec: 200
inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec: 200
```

To speed up things like compaction, I have set those values :

```
$ nodetool getcompactionthroughput
Current compaction throughput: 10000 MB/s

$ nodetool getstreamthroughput
Current stream throughput: 10000 Mb/s

$ nodetool getinterdcstreamthroughput
Current inter-datacenter stream throughput: 10000 Mb/s
```

Cassandra data directories are backed by both SSD and HDD, depending of the keyspace.

Are there any impact (like read or write timeout) of applying such very high values ?

Thank you

Comment: Linking a relevant answer of mine to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69887280/advise-on-stopping-compaction-to-reduce-slowness/69888599#69888599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only impact I can see with high compaction throughput is that your traffic (read/writes) from the application may get impacted. As SSDs have finite IOPS capacity so giving most of it to compaction will impact your traffic at the time compaction is going on.