# How to limit number of validation compactions during repair on Apache Cassandra 3.11

Tags: cassandra

While running full repair on a cassandra cluster with 15 nodes, RF=3 and 3racks(single datacenter) using command ./nodetool repair -pr -full -seq   I can see multiple validation compactions running at the same time (>10). Is there any way to limit simultaneous validations in cassandra 3.11.1 like we can limit normal compactions?

As the cluster size has increased, I limited repairs to run table by table and also used -pr and -seq to restrict load on the nodes. But now, the load is very high due to concurrent validation compactions. Need a way to restrict concurrent validation compactions to reduce load on nodes during repairs. I'm also exploring reaper to manage repairs but need to find some workaround for the load issues till I use reaper.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing (validation) compactions becoming cumbersome, there are two settings that you should look at:

- compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec
- concurrent_compactors

**compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec**

This is the main tuneable setting for compaction.  I mentioned this setting in a related answer here: [Advise on stopping compaction to reduce slowness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69887280/advise-on-stopping-compaction-to-reduce-slowness/)

I would recommend checking this setting, and then reducing it until contention is resolved.  Or, you could try to set compaction throughput to 1 (the lowest setting) during the day.  Then, raise it back up once business hours are over.

```
% bin/nodetool setcompactionthroughput 1
% bin/nodetool getcompactionthroughput
Current compaction throughput: 1 MB/s
```

But definitely check it first, just to see what you're running at, and maybe consider halving that and check the effect.

**concurrent_compactors**

So this defaults to the smaller of (number of disks, # number of cores), with a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 8.  There is some solid advice out there around forcing this to a value of 1 if you're using spinning disks, and maybe set it to 4 for SSDs.  The default is usually fine, but if it's too high, compactions can overwhelm disk I/O.

**tl;dr;**

Focus on compaction throughput for now.  My advise is to check it, lower it, observe it, and repeat until things improve.